# knitr with Shiny: temporary directory

Tags: r, shiny, latex, knitr, pandoc

I've built a Shiny app that estimates a model; I would like the user to be able to download a summary of the model in a pdf format when the estimation is finished. I've included a download button in the app as follows:

```
output$download_estimation = downloadHandler(
  filename = "report.pdf",
  content = function(file) {
    withProgress(message = 'Generating...', {
      rmarkdown::render('report_model.Rmd', output_file = file)
      })
})
```

The file 'report_model.Rmd' uses a custom LaTeX template. The issue is that, whenever I click the download button in Shiny, knitr evaluates the chunks but after that I get a LaTeX error of 'Undefined control sequence.' This occurs because the paths to figures in the report within `\includegraphics{}` are incorrectly specified: instead of using only forwards slashes in the file path, knitr produces a combination of backward and forward slashes, for example

```
\includegraphics{C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Rmksdfj0568\report_model_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-5-1.pdf}.
```

When I knit the exact same document from RStudio outside of Shiny, this does not happen because the .tex is not produced in the temporary directory but rather in the directory where the .Rmd is placed and I get the correct path as

```
\includegraphics{report_model_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-5-1.pdf}.
```

Moreover, when I don't use the custom template but rather the Pandoc built-in one, everything works fine. I was, however, unable to figure out why the use of custom template makes the difference. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue, at least in this specific case, is to include

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(base.dir = normalizePath(tempdir(), winslash = '/'))
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figure/")
```
````

in the beginning of the 'Rmd' file that uses the custom template. This works when the app is run locally, the solution may not work when the app is deployed.